# Extract Table Data from Image-embedded PDF file

Tags: pdf, python-tesseract, pdf2image

To extract Table data from Image-embedded PDF file
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mll8h.png)

I want to improve accuracy of extracting data.
Please leave messages to get table data from Image Embedded PDF.

```
from pdf2image import convert_from_path
import pytesseract
import csv
from pytesseract import Output

# Convert PDF to images
images = convert_from_path('input.pdf')

# Create a CSV file
csv_file_path = 'output.csv'
with open(csv_file_path, 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csv_file:
  csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)

  # Iterate over each image
  for i, image in enumerate(images):
    # Save the image
    image_path = f'page_{i}.png'
    image.save(image_path, 'PNG')

    # Use pytesseract to extract text from the image
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image_path, output_type=Output.STRING)

    # Print the extracted text
    print(text)

    # Write the text to the CSV file
    csv_writer.writerow([text])

print(f'CSV file created at: {csv_file_path}')
```

Comment: Thank you for your attention, K J. Could you provide your source code for extracting data from PDF?

Comment: Thank you, K J. Could you provide URL for online service platform.